# Heartbeats per minute in vanilla HTML JS

Tags: javascript, html, timer

Attached is a fun little snippet demonstrating a button to be clicked along with your heartbeat and see how many beats per minute you're at. This is a mwe of the concept, any feedback is appreciated.

```js
const $ = str => document.querySelector(str);
let beatStart;
let beatEnd;
let beatCount = 0;
const display = $(".display");
function updateDisplay() {
    if (beatCount < 2) return;
    const secondsPassed = (beatEnd - beatStart) / 1000;
    const bpm =  beatCount / secondsPassed * 60;
    display.innerText = bpm.toFixed(2);
}
$(".heart").addEventListener("click", () => {
    beatCount++;
    if (beatStart === undefined) beatStart = Date.now();
    beatEnd = Date.now();
    updateDisplay();
});
$(".reset").addEventListener("click", () => {
    beatStart = undefined;
    beatEnd = undefined;
    beatCount = 0;
    display.innerText = "Tap Tap";
});
```

```html
<span class="display">tap tap</span> bpm
<button class="heart">beat heart</button>
<button class="reset">reset</button>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error!  Notice that even if you tap a steady beat, the display will initially show a high bpm before asymptotically settling down to something approximating the correct value.

The initial placeholder text is "tap tap", but after hitting the reset button, it's "Tap Tap".

I recommend extracting the reset code from the event handler into its own function, so that you can call it to initialize the variables.

If you're using ECMAScript 6 syntax to define functions, you may as well do so consistently everywhere.

```js
const $ = str => document.querySelector(str);

const display = $(".display");
let beatStart, beatEnd, beatCount;

const reset = () => {
    beatStart = undefined;
    beatEnd = undefined;
    beatCount = -1;
    display.innerText = "tap tap";
};

const updateDisplay = () => {
    const secondsPassed = (beatEnd - beatStart) / 1000;
    const bpm =  beatCount / secondsPassed * 60;
    display.innerText = bpm.toFixed(2);
};

$(".heart").addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (beatStart === undefined) beatStart = Date.now();
    beatEnd = Date.now();
    if (++beatCount) updateDisplay();
});
$(".reset").addEventListener("click", reset);

reset();
```

```html
<span class="display">tap tap</span> bpm
<button class="heart">beat heart</button>
<button class="reset">reset</button>
```

Comment: Displaying to the 1/100th of a minute is ludicrous. I predict a significant up-tick in Ambulance company stock as smart watch watchers think they have arrhythmia.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is actually pretty easy to read, and extremely hard to follow.

I do like to see an early return there.

## The "hard to follow"

It is extremely hard to follow because of this single line:

```js
const $ = str => document.querySelector(str);
```

Your code is written like jQuery, looks like jQuery, but is not jQuery.
It's beyond jQuery! I can't believe it's not jQuery!

And likes line this:

```js
$(".heart").addEventListener("click", () => {
    [...]
});
```

They are actually possible in jQuery, but they would look like this:

```js
$(".heart")[0].addEventListener("click", () => {
    [...]
});
```

Which, honestly, it's so easy to miss, if you're used to jQuery.

### The alternative

Just use IDs for the elements, instead of classes.

This way, you can target specific elements with `document.getElementById()`, without using (the slightly slower) `document.querySelector`.

And **please**, avoid making the code look like something it isn't.
Your code isn't going to be read by just you, but by multiple people.
If you make it look like jQuery, people will see it as jQuery.

## The `Date.now()`

If you want to measure the time passed, use `performance.now()` instead of `Date.now()`.

As explained in the [MDN page for `performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now):

> Unlike other timing data available to JavaScript (for example [Date.now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)), the timestamps returned by `performance.now()` are not limited to one-millisecond resolution. Instead, they represent times as floating-point numbers with up to microsecond precision.

> Also unlike `Date.now()`, the values returned by `performance.now()` always increase at a constant rate, independent of the system clock (which might be adjusted manually or skewed by software like NTP). Otherwise, `performance.timing.navigationStart + performance.now()` will be approximately equal to `Date.now()`.

This can cause issues if the clock synchronizes (with NTP) or is changed manually, causing the time to jump forward or backwards at least a few milliseconds.

## Other smaller points

### `updateDisplay`

This function is only used *once*.

It *might* be better to just put the code into the "heart" button click handler.

Personally, I would put the code in the handler, but, if you prefer the separation, it is perfectly valid.

If you decide to keep it separated, that is a perfectly valid thing to do.

### The default output is weird

When there's no "heartbeats", you're showing "tap tap".

Why not use "---.--" instead?
This makes more sense with the "rpm", as "tap tap rpm" is very strange to see...

### Move the buttons

Currently, the buttons shift left and right, depending on the size of the text.

Moving the buttons under the output will probably be a better idea, to avoid accidental clicks on layout shifting.

### The `ifs`...

While this is fine:

```js
if (beatCount < 2) return;
```

It can be harder to read, and can lead to accidental bugs.

If you add braces:

```js
if (beatCount < 2) {
    return;
}
```

It makes it a lot clearer what your intention is, and if you want to add something else to it, you won't be tempted to add them under the `if`:

```js
// Original
if (beatCount < 2) return;

// Possible bad edit 1
if (beatCount < 2) return;
    display.innerText = "One more time!";

// Possible bad edit 2
if (beatCount < 2)
    display.innerText = "One more time!";
    return;
```

If you aren't careful when editing, you can make one of those 2 mistakes, possibly when you're distracted or doing a very quick change.

Comment: `If you make it look like jQuery, people will see it as jQuery.` Great point. I was thinking of suggesting an edit to add a `jQuery` tag. `It might be better to just put the code into the "heart" button click handler.` Not a huge deal, but I disagree. Functions are not just for reusability, but for organizational purposes. I think it's a good use here. As for code style, I'd suggest using curly braces at all times for the `if` statements if only to prevent accidental errors.

Comment: @ChrisSchneider Thank you. I was about to suggest the [tag:jquery] as well, but then I saw that single line. I kinda agree and disagree with you on the separation of the `updateDisplay`, but makes perfect sense to have it separated. Hope my edit shows that both are perfectly fine solutions. And regarding the `if`, I completely forgot about that, so, thank you for reminding me. Hope the changes to my answer are good enough.

Comment: In time I've come to embrace brace-less conditionals, on two conditions: It is only one line, and white space surrounds that line (blank line above and below it).  This, I assert,  is easier to read and usually quicker to interpret.

Comment: *...I would put the [UpdateDisplay()] code in the handler*   Noooooooo...  !  I bet if you do that you'll feel compelled to put a comment on it:  `//Update Display`.  Your honor, I rest my case.

Comment: @radarbob Except, on the original code, there's no empty lines before and after. Still, you do need to be very careful when editing those lines. Regarding the `updateDisplay()`, that comment wouldn't be needed because it would be obvious what it does, since you're changing the `display.innerText`, making the comment redundant. But it is a "mistake" that someone could do.

Comment: `updateDisplay()` as a separate method significantly improves the code. It fits the logical abstraction level of the calling method. 3/4 of `updateDisplay` details obfuscates the central idea; better to encapsulate all that busy work. Expecting the reader to see the bigger picture by parsing out the correct "key" LOC, `display.innerText` let's say, is self delusional. It is the coder's responsibility to convey the meaning, flow, intent, structure, etc. of the program. The reader cannot be expected to read the author's mind nor study ancient hieroglyphs.

Comment: @radarbob I understand your point. As I said, personally, I would put both in the handler myself. But I see why people would want to separate both. I believe both are equally as valid. Maybe separated edges out a little.

Answer (score 1):

### Time.

There is no need to use `Date` to get the time. All events have a time stamp [`Event.timeStamp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/timeStamp) that provides the time the event was created, rather than the time the event was handled.

Though the difference in time between event generation and event handling in this case is inconsequential it is good practice to always be as accurate as possible.

### Data and information

Your app is handling the data (time) poorly (apart from the mistake pointed out in the [existing answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/280187/120556)).

There is a difference between data and information. The data in this case is just time and meaningless in terms of heart beats per minute. This data needs to be interpreted to get the information you are after.

In your existing app you interpolate the data as you get it, using the total time and number of clicks to infer the heart rate.  This is highly inaccurate as you do not consider that the user may pause and not reset.

Rather than track information, track the data and compute the information as and when needed. See rewrite.

### Other points

- Don't use `class` name as a unique element identifier. Rather identify element by giving them a unique `id` within the whole app (HTML, CSS, and JavaScript).
- I disagree with the point in [the answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/280197/120556) in regard to using $. The function's behavior is close enough to jQueries as to warrant its use. The argument that other coders will be confused holds no water. The function's use immediately shows its not jQuery.
- Use named constants to hold values. This gives them meaning. Eg 60 and 1000 are meaningless numbers. `SECONDS_PER_MINUTE` and `MS_PER_SECOND` makes it very clear what the values represent.

### Alternative.

The example below is an alternative approach to the problem. It is a data logger and a data monitor.

- The click event logs time events.
- The `monitor` function interpolate the data. This function poles the data log.

  - It ignores heartbeat values outside the defined range.
  - It automatically resets by interpolating a long tap delay as a reset.

The monitor is a very basic example. A better monitor can include measuring the standard deviation between beats and highlight irregular beat times and much more.

```js
const MINUTE = 60000, MAX_BPM = 180, MIN_BPM = 40;
const MAX_MS_PER_BEAT = MINUTE / MIN_BPM;
const MIN_MS_PER_BEAT = MINUTE / MAX_BPM;
const RESET_MS = MINUTE / (MIN_BPM * 0.7);
const MONITOR_RATE_MS = 1000;
const WAIT_FOR_DATA_MES = "Waiting for data";
const RATE_MES = " BPM";
const dataLog = [];
var samples = -1;

heartBtn.addEventListener("click", e => dataLog.push(e.timeStamp));
(function monitor() {
    if (dataLog.length !== samples) {
        let i = 0, beats = 0, totalTime = 0;
        samples = dataLog.length;
        while (i < samples - 1) {
            const beatTime = dataLog[i + 1] - dataLog[i++];
            if (beatTime >= MIN_MS_PER_BEAT && beatTime <= MAX_MS_PER_BEAT) {
                beats ++;
                totalTime += beatTime;                
            } else if (beatTime >= RESET_MS) {
                const time = dataLog.pop();
                dataLog.length = 0;
                dataLog.push(time);
                break;
            }
        }
        displayEl.textContent = beats ?
            (MINUTE / (totalTime / beats)).toFixed(0) + RATE_MES : WAIT_FOR_DATA_MES;
    }
    setTimeout(monitor, MONITOR_RATE_MS);
})();
```

```css
button {
  font-size: 32px;
}
div {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<button id="heartBtn">Tap heart beat</button>
<div id="displayEl"></div>
```

Comment: "The argument that other coders will be confused holds no water." The fact that, at least 2 persons though it was jQuery, and wanted to add the [tag:jquery] tag to the question actually says otherwise. You do have a good point about using the timestamp from the event. Didn't think about that.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel And what would you think of a coder that added jquery not knowing it was not jQuery being used. Would you let that coder near your (or any comercial) code?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I was the 1st person. They I took a very good look at the weird first line and though "wait, this isn't jQuery...". I explained why the confusion, and why others may fall for the same mistake. Unless you pay close attention, it won't look weird at all, which you won't do when you're trying to quickly see what it does.